# Streaming of data in UDP

Tags: tcp, udp

I found this about UDP, could you please explain me its meaning (with examples possibly)

"Packets have definite boundaries which are honored upon receipt, meaning a read operation at the receiver socket will yield an entire message as it was originally sent."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that UDP Datagrams are received entire and intact or not at all. They may arrive more than once, or out of order.

You can't describe that as 'streaming'.

Each call to `sendto()` or `sendmsg()`sends a single datagram.